# Using nasm with __vectorcall convention

Tags: assembly, nasm, calling-convention

I'm just getting started with nasm and I'm having some issues with the `__vectorcall` convention. When calling my test function (`sinf`), I get an access violation returning from the callee.

```
; float sin_f(float)
global  sin_f@@4
section .text
sin_f@@4:
    push    rdi
;   sub     rsp, 16                 ; make room for xmm
    movss   [rsp - 16], xmm0        ; mov float arg onto stack
    fld     qword [rsp - 16]        ; push argument on float stack
    fsin                            ; do sin in radians
    fstp    qword [rsp - 16]        ; pop float stack
    movss   xmm0, [rsp - 16]        ; move back to xmm0
    movq    rax, xmm0
;   add     rsp, 16                 ; reset stack
    pop     rdi
    ret
```

I'm obviously not doing cleanup correctly, but so far all my tries have failed. Looking at some MSVC dissasembly I've seen they `push/pop rdi`, so I've added that. Instead of `sub/add` to `rsp` (which was causing crashes inside no-mans-land), I just substract directly `rsp`.

This [article](https://jlospinoso.github.io/assembly/c/developing/software/2015/04/04/common-x86-calling-conventions.html) covers popular calling conventions, and mentions `__vectorcall` being similar to `__fastcall`. However, using `ret 4` doesn't change anything. Plus MSVC doesn't do that itself. Oh and I'm also moving to `rax` just because.

Any help with these concepts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

edit: The error is

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF6198B2C5A in demo1.exe:
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000B817FA20
```

Caller disassembly:

```
; 13   : T sin(T angle) {

$LN3:
    movss   DWORD PTR [rsp+8], xmm0
    push    rdi
    sub rsp, 48                 ; 00000030H
    mov rdi, rsp
    mov ecx, 12
    mov eax, -858993460             ; ccccccccH
    rep stosd

; 14   :    static_assert(std::is_floating_point_v<T>, "requires floating point");
; 15   :    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<float, T>) {
; 16   :        return detail::sin_f(angle);

    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR angle$[rsp]
    call    sin_f@@8

; 17   :    } else {
; 18   :        return detail::sin_d(angle);
; 19   :    }
; 20   : 
; 26   : }

    add rsp, 48                 ; 00000030H
    pop rdi
    ret 0
```

Comment: Side note: `movss` is a float not a double. You **must** uncomment the `sub rsp, 16 ` and the `add rsp, 16` as windows does not provide red zone (I assume you are on windows since you mentioned MSVC). In that case of course you should use `[rsp]` and not `[rsp-16]`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I am using floats (`float sin_f(float)`). I just read about the red zone. I'm trying with `sub rsp, 24` as per the nasm doc. Could it be an alignement issue? The program is being compiled with custom alignement.

Comment: Alignment doesn't matter here. Update your question with the current version of the code. PS: if you do have floats then of course the `qword` is wrong in the FPU instructions as that is for a double. `ret 4` is definitely broken, you want simple `ret`.

Comment: @Jester OK I tried using dword (and removing the ret value) still nothing. Will update again.

Comment: That looks correct. I suspect the error is elsewhere. What does that IP map to? Can you single step the code from the `ret` onwards? Can you also post disassembly of the calling function?

Comment: Yep, I think I'm getting somewhere now. It seems to want @@8 for the name. I thought the number after @@ was the byte size of the arguments (a single float in this instance). The exception is also difference now. At least its trying to access an adress (not `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`)

Comment: Windows x64 `__vectorcall` (and the "normal" x64 `__fastcall`) have shadow space *above* RSP you can use as scratch space.  A red zone is space below RSP you can use without signal-handlers or anything else clobbering it, so that's the wrong terminology.  (scx: if you actually read about red zones, then go search again for shadow space.  Or see the links to ABI docs in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

Comment: @PeterCordes original code was using `[rsp-16]` which would have been red zone except there is no such thing on windows, hence an error.

Comment: @Jester: oops, skimmed your comment too fast.

Comment: Anyway, instead of `sub rsp`, you can use a slot of shadow space to store/reload.  (Or better, implement it as `void sin_f(const float *in, float *out)` to save store/reload round trips.  That costs the caller instructions to set up the pointer args, but that's pretty cheap and gives you the option of working in place or writing the result to a temporary.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I was quite baffled reading the disassembled code and seeing additions to to RSP. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the main problem was using `@@4` for the byte size. For some reason it needs to be `@@8`. Maybe because of the return value?

Also, I messed up the 64/32 bit calls. This is the final working version:

```
; float sin_f(float)
global  sin_f@@8
section .text
sin_f@@8:
    sub     rsp, 24         ; red-zone
    movss   [rsp], xmm0     ; mov float arg onto stack
    fld     dword [rsp]     ; push argument on float stack
    fsin                            ; do sin in radians
    fstp    dword [rsp]     ; pop float stack
    movss   xmm0, [rsp]     ; move back to xmm0
    add     rsp, 24         ; red-zone
    ret
```

Comment: This is the same code as your question, which you claim doesn't work.  I think you need to roll back your question so it actually has the bugs this answer claims to fix.  Otherwise it's not a question anymore.

Comment: @PeterCordes I reverted the sample to its original incarnation.